# How to add og:video tag at my site?

Tags: 6, meta-tags

I want to share my video site on Facebook.
Facebook detect only thumbnail of video.
I see France24.com add og:video on the source of site and show direct video on facebook.
I use [auto_opengraph](http://drupal.org/project/auto_opengraph) but this module can't generate `og:video` 
How  can i do?

Answer (score 0):

new version of [XML Sitemap](http://drupal.org/project/xmlsitemap) module helped me.

> The XML sitemap module creates a sitemap that conforms to the
>   sitemaps.org specification. This helps search engines to more
>   intelligently crawl a website and keep their results up to date. The
>   sitemap created by the module can be automatically submitted to Ask,
>   Google, Bing (formerly Windows Live Search), and Yahoo! search
>   engines. The module also comes with several submodules that can add
>   sitemap links for content, menu items, taxonomy terms, and user
>   profiles.

Answer (score 0):

try this in your module

```
$tags =array();
//add stuff to tags    
 foreach($tags['og'] as $key => $value)
                 {
                  $meta = array(
                    '#tag' => 'meta',
                    '#attributes' => array(
                      'property' => 'og:' . $key,
                      'content' => $value
                    )
                  );
                  drupal_add_html_head($meta, 'og_meta' . $key);
                 }
```